# How to show if $gf$ is 1-1, $f$ is 1-1?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

Let $f: A \rightarrow B$ and $g: B \rightarrow C$ be functions.

> If $gf$ is 1-1, prove $f$ is 1-1.

$\underline{Proof.}$

Assume $g(f(x_0)), g(f(x_1)) \in C.$

Then $g(f(x_0)) = g(f(x_1)) \Longrightarrow f(x_0) = f(x_1)$.

But now I am stuck on the proof. For example, I can't just say this implies $x_0 = x_1$; for example, the inverse of $4$ is $[-2, 2]$ when talking about square roots.

Comment: Your proof seems to be thinking $g$ is 1-1, but in fact $gf$ is 1-1. Try to start by supposing $f(x_0) = f(y_0)$ then you get $g(f(x_0)) = g(f(y_0))$, what does this say about $x_0$ and $y_0$ using the fact that $gf$ is 1-1?

Comment: If I suppose $f(x_0) = f(y_0)$, why can I make the assumption $g(f(x_0)) = g(f(x_1))$? @DevenWare

Comment: if $f(x_0) = f(y_0)$ then $g(f(x_0)) = g(f(y_0))$ because you are plugging in the same value into $g$ both times

Comment: By the definition of a function, of course. Is that correct? @Deven Ware

Comment: Yeah, thats correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint:* $$f(x) = f(y) \Longrightarrow g(f(x)) = g(f(y)).$$

Comment: f(x) = y = f(y)?

Comment: No. $g(f(x)) = g(f(y)) \Longrightarrow x=y$.

Comment: Also, it's the other way around.

Comment: Why? "gf is 1-1" means $g(f(x)) = g(f(y)) \Longrightarrow x=y$.

Comment: @njguliyev Is that because that is the definition of a function, that is, there is a unique $f(x) : x \in A$? It certainly is not because g(f(x))=g(f(y))⟹x=y.

Answer (score 2):

We want to show that if $f(x)=f(y)$ then $x=y$. But remember that if $f(x)=f(y)$, then $g(f(x))=g(f(y))$ and so $(g\circ f)(x)=(g\circ f)(y)$. As $g\circ f$ is 1-1 we can conclude that $x=y$.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is wrong, you don't know that $g$ is injective.

Suppose $f$ is not injective, i.e. $f(x) = f(y)$ for some pair $x\neq y$, then $(gf)(x) = g(f(x)) = g(f(y)) = (gf)(y)$. However we know that $gf$ is injective and so this forces $x=y$, creating a contradiction.